# How to import csv file into database without losing leading zeros of numbers in columns

Tags: csv, phpmyadmin

I exported a database table as csv file, modified it and then I am trying to reimport it. But the columns having data like "001", "002", "003" etc which is type `TEXT` becomes "1", "2", "3" on importing into the database via php myadmin, meaning I am loosing leading zeros.

Please help

Comment: What is the column type?

Comment: Text format as mentioned in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved when I converted the file to sql format with an online csv to sql converter. Then I opened the file in notepad++ and made sure the structure of the fields and table was the same as the previous file. And when I uploaded the file, the leading zeros were retained.